# Understanding different types of energy - potential, kinetic, mechanical, and internal

Tags: energy, energy-conservation

I'm trying to understand the different types of energy -- is the following organization of the different energy types technically a 'correct' way of organizing these concepts?

[image]

Comment: I can't make much sense of this table.

Comment: The top two rows and the left 3 columns are headings?

Comment: On which basis it looks wrong for a number of reasons. Kinetic energy and thermal energy are similar, There is no distinction between Gravitational Kinetic energy ands any other type of kinetic energy - which is to say there is only one type of kinetic energy, energy due to motion.

Comment: The Potential energy column fares better, if you look up the range of the forces involved you will see the scale at which such forces interact. Whether there isn't a threshold scale below which we would call them "internal". Mechanical means kinetic energy, so I think it is a poor word choice.

Comment: Try this for some background; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_interaction

Comment: What is electrical kinetic energy?

Answer (score 2):

There is no place for light in your table, so the answer to your question is no. There are so many more types of energy that would expand your table and make it much more complex. For example, an elementary particle may be describesd by having close to 30 different quantum numbers, of which the electric charge is just one and each adds mass/energy to the particle.

Also, not all potential energy is true energy. True energy adds mass according to E=mc2. So consider this example. If I lift an object and its gravitational potential energy changes, does the mass also change according to the above formula? I don't think so, but I will let the experts comment to clarify this point. As far as I know, energy is conserved in uniform time and time is not uniform in gravity. So the gravitational potential energy is a nice mathematical trick, but does it actually add any mass to an object, especially considering this "energy" is negative?

Is the energy of a fidget spinner kinetic or potential. What if the spinner is in a box and you don't actually know what is inside? What if the spinner is very small, like a molecule? And what if it is really big, like a galaxy? Its energy is still different from the kinetic energy of a straignt movement, because the latter is lost in the expanding universe (similar to the redshift), but the spinner energy is not lost and therefore a completely different type. Where would you put it in your table?

Keep trying, may be some day you'll create a "periodic table of energy" :)